# Specify different JPA @QueryHint values for tests

Tags: java, jpa, junit, spring-data-jpa

I have a Spring Data / JPA application that relies on the following query hint to allow it to run on mySql, our production database.

`@QueryHints(value = @QueryHint(name = HINT_FETCH_SIZE, value = "" + Integer.MIN_VALUE))`

I want to write a unit test to test the Query, but the in-memory database that `DataJpaTest` provides doesn't support a Fetch size of Integer.MIN_VALUE. If I manually edit the value to "1", then all is fine.

Is there a way to dynamically alter the value that I pass to the QueryHint at compile time so that I can use different values for test and production?